# C++ class that can hold one of a set of classes that all inherit from a common class

Tags: c++

What are the ways in C++ to handle a class that has ownership of an instance of another class, where that instance could potentially be of a number of classes all of which inherit from a common class?

Example:

```
class Item { //the common ancestor, which is never used directly
public:
  int size;
}

class ItemWidget: public Item { //possible class 1
public:
  int height;
  int width;
}

class ItemText: public Item { //possible class 2
  std::string text;
}
```

Let's say there is also a class `Container`, each of which contains a single Item, and the only time anyone is ever interested in an Item is when they are getting it out of the Container. Let's also say Items are only created at the same time the Container is created, for the purpose of putting them in the Container.

What are the different ways to structure this? We could make a pointer in Container for the contained Item, and then pass arguments to the constructor of Container for what sort of Item to call new on, and this will stick the Items all in the heap. Is there a way to store the Item in the stack with the Container, and would this have any advantages?

Does it make a difference if the Container and Items are immutable, and we know everything about them at the moment of creation, and will never change them?

Comment: look into std::vector<> you want to have then something like std::vector<base_class *> 

but why would you like to have a container of base_class types where the subclasses have nothing in common? the base class should rather be an interface otherwise this piece of code wouldn't be too usefull.

Comment: Also: _virtual destructor_. You need one if you're going to do this.

Comment: @Alex I specified each Container contains a single Item, so what would be the benefit of using a vector of pointers? Why do the subclasses have nothing in common? What if the subclasses are all used in the same way (let's say each Item is an item to be displayed graphically in the above example, and there can be widgets and text)? Then the base class provides a central way to store both a few common variables (one in the example) as well as a way to address the pointer rather than using a void pointer?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas could you elaborate a little why that's necessary in this situation? Wouldn't all the destructor needs be handled implicitly by the simple subclasses in the example?

Comment: @Nantucket: Presumably the container class will own the objects and destroy them. It is undefined behavior to destroy an object via a pointer/reference to its base class if that base class does not have a virtual destructor. Without such a destructor, the proper derived class destructors will not be called, and the heap may even be damaged.

Comment: If you don't want the container to take ownership (which cannot really be done without dynamic allocation (please forget the "heap", you can write your own crazy stack allocator if you really must)), then you could take a look at Boost's "intrusive containers", which don't take ownership...

Comment: @Nantucket: its generally a bad behaviour to inherit variables public. make variables in Object oriented languages private and define functions that make something with them (and those should be public). this increases encapsulation

Comment: @Kerrek, the first sentences says, "has ownership".

Comment: @Marcelo: Fair enough. I'm struggling a bit with the whole "mustn't be on the heap" thing.

Comment: OK, going out on a limb here: In order to exploit polymorphism, you need a reference or a pointer. If you only want to write a single class that manages a polymorphic collection, you must pass it a reference to your concrete object, which it then must copy ("has ownership") and *keep its own copy somewhere*. If you don't want a separate class type for each concrete object, that immediately necessitates dynamic allocation. (I would again like to remind the OP that dynamic allocation has nothing to do with a heap.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB Okay, clearly I have a lot to learn on this subject. However, it was my understanding that whenever you call new on an object, this is a dyanmic allocation which will take place on the heap, is this incorrect? This seems to be what it says on Wikipedia as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: @Nantucket: "Dynamic" means, and *only* means, that *you* are responsible for the clean-up. Placement-new for example, as used in my answer, allows you to construct the object anywhere you like. Do not confuse memory allocation with object construction. C++ doesn't, and neither should you. The entire standard library is crucially built around this idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correct solution looks like:

```
class Container {
public:
    /* ctor, accessors */
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Item> item;
};
```

If you have an old compiler, you can use `std::auto_ptr` instead.

The smart pointer ensures strict ownership of the item by the container. (*You could as well make it a plain pointer and roll up your own destructor/assignment op/copy ctor/move ctor/ move assignment op/ etc, but `unique_ptr` has it all already done, so...*)

**Why do you need to use a pointer here, not just a plain composition?**

Because if you compose, then you must know the exact class which is going to be composed. You can't introduce polymorphism. Also the size of all `Container` objects must be the same, and the size of `Item`'s derived classes may vary.

**And if you desperately need to compose?**

Then you need as many variants of `Container` as there are the items stored, since every such Container will be of different size, so it's a different class. Your best shot is:

```
struct IContainer {
    virtual Item& getItem() = 0;
};

template<typename ItemType>
struct Container : IContainer {
    virtual Item& getItem() {
        return m_item;
    }
private:
    ItemType m_item;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, crazy idea. Don't use this:

```
class AutoContainer
{
  char buf[CRAZY_VALUE];
  Base * p;

public:

  template <typename T> AutoContainer(const T & x)
    : p(::new (buf) T(x))
  {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "Invalid use of AutoContainer");
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= CRAZY_VAL, "Not enough memory for derived class.");
#ifdef __GNUC__
    static_assert(__has_virtual_destructor(Base), "Base must have virtual destructor!");
#endif
  }

  ~AutoContainer() { p->~Base(); }

  Base & get() { return *p; }
  const Base & get() const { return *p; }
};
```

The container requires no dynamic allocation itself, you must only ensure that `CRAZY_VALUE` is big enough to hold any derived class.

Comment: About CRAZY_VALUE, why not throw another static assert into the template? Looks correct but EVIL! :D

Comment: @Kos: like minds :-) I'd also make the size a template parameter, and the base class type, etc etc...

Comment: `boost::variant` does something similar to this (although you must have a complete list of types that you might need to use)

Comment: @bdolan: With a complete list of types you could get the maximal required size...

Comment: BTW i have a feeling that this could pictureously fail if the derived class multiply inherits. [citation needed]

Answer (score 1):

the example code below compiles and shows how to do something similar to what you want to do. this is what in java would be called interfaces. see that you need at least some similarity in the classes (a common function name in this case). The virtual keyword means that all subclasses need to implement this function and whenever that function is called the function of the real class is actually called.

whether the classes are const or not doesn't harm here. but in general you should be as const correct as possible. because the compiler can generate better code if it knows what will not be changed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class outputter {
  public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class foo : public outputter {
  public:
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
 };

 class bar : public outputter {
   public:
     virtual void print() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }
 };




int main(){
  std::vector<outputter *> vec;
  foo *f = new foo;
  vec.push_back(f);
  bar *b = new bar ;
  vec.push_back(b);
  for ( std::vector<outputter *>::iterator i = 
        vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i )
  { 
    (*i)->print();
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   foo
   bar
```

Comment: Don't forget to `delete` each of the `outputter`s in the vector when you're done!

Answer (score 1):

Hold a pointer (preferably a smart one) in the container class, and call a pure virtual `clone()` member function on the Item class that is implemented by the derived classes when you need to copy. You can do this in a completely generic way, thus:

```
class Item {
    // ...
private:
    virtual Item* clone() const = 0;
    friend Container; // Or make clone() public.
};

template <class I>
class ItemCloneMixin : public Item {
private:
    I* clone() const { return new I(static_cast<const I&>(*this); }
};

class ItemWidget : public ItemCloneMixin<ItemWidget> { /* ... */ };
class ItemText : public ItemCloneMixin<ItemText> { /* ... */ };
```

Regarding stack storage, you can use an overloaded new that calls `alloca()`, but do so at your peril. It will only work if the compiler inlines your special new operator, which you can't force it to do (except with non-portable compiler pragmas). My advice is that it just isn't worth the aggravation; runtime polymorphism belongs on the heap.